# Migrating from one cluster to a new one in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

I have 7-8 different microservices running on google cloud. 
I'm planning to do API monitoring and I've been asked to use google's stackdriver trace for it.

However it turns out, you [cannot](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs) use stackdriver trace for an existing cluster. So, I approached my higher ups and they asked me to migrate to a new cluster with all the required permissions provisioned.

My argument is, it is not really worth to migrate from a perfectly working cluster to a new one. I proposed a [different](http://swaggerstats.io/) method for API monitoring. The proposed method doesn't nudge my existing micro-services, however requires a bit more effort. (Like, setting up elastic search and kibana).

Also, I would have to modify some parts of my CD pipeline, made using google's cloud build, if I were to migrate to a new cluster.

So, I'm looking for opinions about what a good approach could be in my case.